# Coordinate of a graphics object in java

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, affinetransform

My question is: how to find the coordinate of a graphic object that are drawn on a buffered image?

for example: I have a rectangle drawn on screen by using `BufferedImage`. So when I rotate it by using affine transform, the coordinate of the top left corner is stay the same because `AffineTransform` rotate the axis of that BufferedImage.

So how can I find the coordinate of the rectangle after rotating at its centre?

Thank in advanced!

Comment: Have you tried `AffineTransformOp` and its `getPoint2D()` and `getBounds2D()` methods? They are made for exactly this use case.

Comment: The question is rather unclear for me. Do you want to rotate a `BufferedImage` around its center? Or do you want to know the corner points of a `BufferedImage` that was rotated with an arbitrary `AffineTransform`?...

Comment: this is what i want: corner points of a BufferedImage that was rotated with an arbitrary AffineTransform. Thanks! I'm trying the affinetransformOp now. But if you have any other way to do, please help! :)